# Does anyone know what "SLCC2" stands for in the IE 11 userAgent string

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I have looked everywhere I can find and although I can find explanations for many different parts of the IE userAgent string, I cannot find an explanation for this part.  **What does SLCC2 stand for?**

The reason I ask is that we have a small number of users experiencing a problem on our site.  But they are on the same browser and platform as other users not having this issue.  One of the common items with the people having problems is this code in their userAgent string. So I am trying to find out what this indicates.

Here is the userAgent string in full:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; **SLCC2;** .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.useragentstring.com/index.php?id=16891 SLCC2 refers to:

> Microsoft-Windows-Security-Licensing-SLCC component SLCC is a service for the Windows Anytime upgrade process in Vista and Server 2008. Allows upgrade from Vista Home Basic to Vista Ultimate Edition, or Server 2008 Standard to Server 2008 Enterprise